# QLCDNumber numbers can't be centered

Tags: c++, qt, digit, lcd, qlcdnumber

Why QLCDNumber numbers can't be centered when the number of digits is lower than the number of digits allowed in the parameters of QLCDNumber ?
Can I bypass this ?

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you can set the number of digits each time you set a new value :

```
ui->lcdNumber->display(value);
ui->lcdNumber->setDigitCount(QString("%1").arg(value).length());
```

Here `QString("%1").arg(value).length()` returns the number of digits in `value`. When you set it properly it would be aligned correctly.

Comment: "`value/10+1` returns the number of digits in `value`" - really? There are 10 digits in the value `99`?

Comment: @TobySpeight That was a bad mistake. You are right, it's corrected now.